# MailChimp Path parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, mailchimp

I'm trying to build a standart mailchimp call using node,and looking at the documentation I need to add a path parameter and it gives this example :

`https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{list_id}/members/{email_id}/notes/{id}`

The problem is,I can't find the email_id and the id after notes. The list_id is very easy to find,but the others I can't find them. Anyone know where they are? Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The email ID is the MD5 hash of the email address. This is described in the [MailChimp Documentation](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/manage-subscribers-with-the-mailchimp-api/).

Unfortunately MailChimp does not provide you with the MD5 hash so you will have to generate it yourself. There is an npm module called [md5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md5). If you install that you can generate the MD5 like so:

```
var md5 = require('md5');
console.log(md5('email@subscriber.com'));
```

Comment: Do you know where to find the md5 hash?

Comment: Thank you so much! What about the "/notes/{id}" at the end? are they needed?

Comment: I've got no idea what you are trying to do with the API so I can't say.